# Использование класса regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании класса Regex. Вот в чём собственно проблема. Написал в консоли небольшой код.

```
string a = "456"; 
Regex rgx = new Regex("^\\d{0,}$"); 
if (rgx.IsMatch(a)) 
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Условие выполнилось как и должно. Всё нормально.
В asp.net приложении мне нужно пропустить текст бокс через Regex но там почему то те же цифры условия не выполняют. Попробовал упростить и написать то же самое что и в консоли, но условие всё равно не выполнилось, вот код.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
try 
{ 
string a = "456"; 
Regex rgx = new Regex("^\\d{ 0, }$"); 
if (rgx.IsMatch(a)) 
throw new Exception("Некорректно введено поле Диапазон номеров труб C"); 
} 
catch(Exception ex) 
{ 
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + ex.Message + "')", true); 
return; 
} 
con.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into client (name, surname) values (@name, @surname)", con); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", TextBox2.Text); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close(); 
FillGrid(); 
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Знакомый сказал что может быть проблема в culture. В таком случае как посмотреть и сравнить culture в обоих приложениях и выставить нужную, что бы всё работало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убери пробелы в фигурных скобках

```
string a = "456"; 
Regex rgx = new Regex("^\\d{0,}$"); 
if (rgx.IsMatch(a)){
   Console.WriteLine("zer_good");
} else {
   Console.WriteLine("NO zer_good");
}
```

Comment: Ещё можно использовать параметр `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`.